# How to update set.position.x via addEventListener dynamically on three.js?

Tags: three.js

I've got a button that has addEventListener with a parameter about to be passed. If I console.log(*referenced button element*) it consoles just fine. As a result I get Vector3 {x: 15, y: 0, z: 0} with no error displayed on console. The problem is that I cannot / not acknowledged yet on how to / update changes dynamically via dom / console in order to set cube X position to be RErendered whenever the button with argument is presented (pressed). My code fragment:

```
        var button = document.getElementById("increment");
        button.addEventListener("click", function() { onButtonClick (15)}, false);

        function onButtonClick(customX) {
            var webGLcontext = document.getElementById("WebGL-output");
            webGLcontext = cube.position;
            webGLcontext.set(customX, 0, 0);
            scene.add(webGLcontext);}

       // all the rest stuff of three.js skeleton presented
        }
       // THREE.Object3D.add: object not an instance of THREE.Object3D. Vector3 {x: 15, y: 0, z: 0}
```

Any help or reference to an article of this topic would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you set animation loop?

Comment: Probably not, Sir. Any chance how to do this (syntaxical example)? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can to the things with this option (it's just a concept, not the ultimate solution):

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 100);
camera.position.set(0, 8, 13);
camera.lookAt(scene.position);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

scene.add(new THREE.GridHelper(10, 10));

var box = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(), new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial());
scene.add(box);

[{
    id: 'btnUp',
    move: new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -1)
  },
  {
    id: 'btnRight',
    move: new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0)
  },
  {
    id: 'btnDown',
    move: new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1)
  },
  {
    id: 'btnLeft',
    move: new THREE.Vector3(-1, 0, 0)
  }
].forEach(a => {
  let btn = document.getElementById(a.id);
  btn.addEventListener("click", event => {
    box.position.add(a.move); // move the cube in the desired direction
  });
});

renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => { // animation loop
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
});
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

#btnButtons {
  position: absolute;
}

button {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<div id="btnButtons">
  <button id="btnUp">&uarr;</button>
  <button id="btnRight">&rarr;</button>
  <button id="btnDown">&darr;</button>
  <button id="btnLeft">&larr;</button>
</div>
```

When you move the cube, you'll see how its position change automatically, as the scene will be rendered in the animation loop at certain frame rate.

Comment: You nailed it, sir! And of course saved a lot of time. THANK YOU :)))